# QList inside function template

Tags: c++, qt, templates, compilation

I am trying to create a function template containing a `QList` iterator :

```
template <typename T> void funcTemplate()
{
    QList<T>::ConstIterator it;
}
```

I get:

> In function 'void funcTemplate()': error: expected ';' before 'it'

I tried lots of things but I can't make it compile.
It is really strange because I can create a QList without problems:

```
template <typename T> void funcTemplate()
{
    QList<T> list;
}
```

Does anybody has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You need `typename` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
template <typename T> void funcTemplate()
{
    typename QList<T>::ConstIterator it;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't really know how nested templates work. I had no idea how to find this solution. I am going to read the other thread.